# Updating database row for a group of people

Tags: sql, sql-server

Newbie. SQL Server 2014

I am trying to update a flag, but am unsure of the structure. Here's a simplified snip of what I am doing

```
update tblCustomer 
set IsHappy=true 
where country=1 and 
firstname in (ian,bob,sam,joe)
```

Any ideas how to do this in one line?

Comment: Anything else wrong than missing 's from the names?

Comment: I have such an idea. Just delete all new line characters and you will get one line.

Comment: It is just "one line" i.e. one sql query. The problem is in your `IN` clause. Pass the the valid expression i.e. `char` or `varchar`.

Comment: Just do firstname in ('ian', 'bob', 'sam', 'joe'), and you are probably done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, put your string literals in single quotes, and T-SQL doesn't know "true" or "false" - it's `1` (for true) or `0` (for false) for a `BIT` column.

```
update tblCustomer 
set IsHappy = 1 
where country = 1 
  and firstname in ('ian', 'bob', 'sam', 'joe')
```